# Determiners usage with phrases

Tags: phrase-meaning, verbs, determiners

Our life was fine until we experienced Rocky, **the/a** **neighbour's dog that** **chases our cat.**

Are the determiners always necessary to govern the connection of the noun phrase with the rest of the sentence in examples like these?

For, instance, this example sounds ok, may be spoken this way, but is missing the determiner.

Our life was fine until we experienced Rocky, **bane of our existence.** (missing the)

As opposed to this example where it just doesn't work.

Our life was fine until we experienced Rocky, **dog that chases our cat.**

I wasn't sure if the determiners are always necessary in phrases that sound ok without them,  or just for semantic clarity.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that "Rocky, bane of our existence" sounds ok, is because **it seems like "Bane of our Existence" is a epithet, title, or nickname**. It sound similar to "Ned Stark, Lord of Winterfell" etc. If you do not intend to treat "bane of our existence" as such, then there really should be a determiner such as "the".